# Use JavaScript to find element by its CSS property value

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I find the element by matching its CSS property value?

For example, if the background color of the element is green, then do something...

```js
const elm = document.getElementsByClassName('elm');

[...elm].forEach(function(s) {
  //find the element which background color is green
  
  //then console.log(theItem)
})
```

```css
.elm {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.elm1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.elm2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.elm3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="elm elm1"></div>
<div class="elm elm2"></div>
<div class="elm elm3"></div>
```

Comment: [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) can help, but in this particular example, you can just use `.getElementsByClassName('elm2')`

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks, I saw the doc and he is using the `getComputedStyle` for one element, I couldn't think of how to use this to check multiple items with the same class name...

Comment: In your code your already have a loop in place that goes through all of your elements, so `s` is a single element which you can check the styles of, and then push into an array if it has the colour you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method on each of your elements to check and see if an element has your green background colour. For the `green` colour, the computed style for this is the RGB colour of `rgb(0, 128, 0)`. By using `.filter()` you can return a new array of elements that have a computed background color of this value:

```js
const elm = document.getElementsByClassName('elm');

const greenElms = [...elm].filter(function(s) {
  const bgColor = getComputedStyle(s).backgroundColor;
  return bgColor === "rgb(0, 128, 0)";
});
console.log(greenElms);
```

```css
.elm {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.elm1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.elm2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.elm3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="elm elm1"></div>
<div class="elm elm2"></div>
<div class="elm elm3"></div>
```

However, most of the time, your CSS is static, so you would know at the time of writing your JS code what the styles/selectors are that are responsible for styling your elements, and so you can instead use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to match the same elements that the green background style is applying to, eg:

```js
const greenElms = document.querySelectorAll('.elm2'); // NodeList (similar to an array)
console.log(greenElms);
```

```css
.elm {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.elm1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.elm2 {
  background-color: green;
}

.elm3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="elm elm1"></div>
<div class="elm elm2"></div>
<div class="elm elm3"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, the first solution is great but is it possible to make the greenElms an element instead of an object? The filter function returns an object, the reason I use `getElementsByClassName` is that I need it to be an element.

Comment: @nakar20966 The filter function returns an array of elements. What do you want as the result if you have multiple green elements? Do you just want the first?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection (which is similar to an array) of elements. It doesn't return a singular element.

Comment: If you just want one element, you can change `.filter()` to be `.find()`

Comment: Actually, I wanna programmatically find an element that matches the condition like its background color, then get its attribute like `greenElms.getAttribute(src)`. But I've just tried using your first solution, unfortunately, it doesn't work because I've just realized that it's an array

Comment: @nakar20966 but what happens when you have two elements with the same background colour that you're searching for? Do you want to check both? Or just the first element with the background colour.

Comment: I just need the first element because I'm sure there will only be one element matching the condition. I've just tried changing the `filter` to the `find`method and it's working perfectly now! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nick Parsons answer, I came up with a way to search any property in any element:

```js
const searchByProperty = (property) =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*')).filter((s) => {
        const value = getComputedStyle(s)[property];
        console.log(property, value);
    });
```

Usage:

```js
searchByProperty('backgroundColor');
```